# The use of ITextRange interface in UWP Vs. TextRange object in WPF

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

While attempting to convert an `WPF` code (shown at the end) into `UWP` code, I'm encountering two challenges:

1. UWP equivalent of [TexRange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.textrange?view=netframework-4.7.2) object in WPF.
2. UWP equivalent of [TexRange.Load(...)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.textrange.load?view=netframework-4.7.2) method in WPF.

I have created a [TextRange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.text.itextrange) in UWP as follows:

```
var richTextBox = new RichEditBox();
richTextBox.Document.GetText(TextGetOptions.None, out string rebText);
ITextRange textRange = richTextBox.Document.GetRange(0, rebText.Length-1);
```

But `ITextRange` object of UWP does not seems to have a Load() method.

**Question**:

1. Will the above `textRange` in UWP perform the same as the `textRange` object of WPF in the following WPF code; or they will behave differently in UWP than in WPF?
2. Since `ITextRange` object of UWP does not have a `.Load(..)` method, how do I deal with the Load(…) method in my UWP code while converting the following code of WPF into UWP app?

**The WPF code to be migrated to UWP app**:

```
private static string ConvertRtfToXaml(string rtfText)
{
    var richTextBox = new RichTextBox();
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(rtfText)) return "";

    var textRange = new TextRange(richTextBox.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox.Document.ContentEnd);

    //Create a MemoryStream of the Rtf content

    using (var rtfMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var rtfStreamWriter = new StreamWriter(rtfMemoryStream))
        {
            rtfStreamWriter.Write(rtfText);
            rtfStreamWriter.Flush();
            rtfMemoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            //Load the MemoryStream into TextRange ranging from start to end of RichTextBox.
            textRange.Load(rtfMemoryStream, DataFormats.Rtf);
        }
    }

    using (var rtfMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {

        textRange = new TextRange(richTextBox.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox.Document.ContentEnd);
        textRange.Save(rtfMemoryStream, DataFormats.Xaml);
        rtfMemoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        using (var rtfStreamReader = new StreamReader(rtfMemoryStream))
        {
            return rtfStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Since ITextRange object of UWP does not have a .Load(..) method, how do I deal with the Load(…) method in my UWP code while converting the following code of WPF into UWP app?

In UWP, you could use the [ITextDocument.SaveToStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.text.itextdocument.savetostream) and [ITextDocument.LoadFromStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.text.itextdocument.loadfromstream) method.

You could check the sample on [RichEditBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.richeditbox#examples) document.

Comment: But the `TextGetOptions` parameter of `ITextDocument.SaveToStream` method does not have an option to save to stream in `Xaml` as data format [Ref: [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.text.textgetoptions)]. And the above `WPF` code is using `textRange.Save(rtfMemoryStream, DataFormats.Xaml);`. So, what will be it's equivalent?

Comment: @nam You're right. For now, there's no such a data format. You could submit a **Feature Request** on [WPDev UserVoice](http://wpdev.uservoice.com/).